# get rid of decimal scale of stock field in commerce

Tags: 7, entities, commerce

product shows stock as 1.00 -> how do i get it to show 1
(i get this to work in admin lists : admin/commerce/product
but when showing in start screen or product detail page its 1.00..

how can I get rid of `.00` ?

**notice:** I have and create some product and in `admin/commerce/products/types/product/fields/commerce_stock`  stock field property it is disabled

**edited**
I update the module to new released , I unnistall fully pervious version and install new, all stock set 0, in display of product display I can do it that dont show scale digits .00, but in edit of product display it is 0.00 with 2 digit scale yet

[image]

Comment: What version of https://drupal.org/project/commerce_stock are you using? https://drupal.org/node/1426066 says that's fixed.

Comment: @jonpeck Yes, I am using `commerce_stock` module

Comment: No,Its not fixed for me, in commerce_stock field property it have a property `scale` and set to `2` , it is disable and I can change it. do you have a idea?

Comment: Which version of that module are you using?

Comment: I use 7.x-2.0-alpha4 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[That bug has been fixed a long time ago](https://drupal.org/node/1426066); update from 7.x-2.0-alpha4 to 7.x-2.0-rc1. https://drupal.org/project/commerce_stock and that will fix it, along with a lot of other issues.

Comment: I update it, but yet in edit product display it is decimal with 2 scale !!!

Comment: Editing only, not shown to users? I'm confident that's by design.

Comment: yes, only in editing :(

Comment: That's not a bug. If you'd like to change how commerce_stock works, I'd suggest submitting a feature request to https://drupal.org/project/issues/commerce_stock

Comment: finally you tell me we can change stock field in edit ?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry folks, but i believe this is still an issue in current version `7.x-2.1`.
Although there is a decimal formatter option available in the manage display tab of the product settings page, it has no effect if you render the data outside *Default*, *Full content*, *Line Item* or *Teaser* settings.

For example if you load commerce product like this in a form template :

```
$product = commerce_product_load((int)$form['product_id']['#value']);
```

It still renders with default defined 2 decimal positions

[image]